# Tkinter Combobox with two variables

Tags: python, tkinter

```
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import ttk
 from random import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.c = randint(1, 50)
        self.o = randint(60, 100)
        varClose.set(self.c)
        varOpen.set(self.o)
        Close = varClose.get()
        Open = varOpen.get()
        self.Mylist = ttk.Combobox(width=10)
        self.Mylist['values'] = (Close, Open)
        self.Mylist.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky=W)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('420x220')
varClose = IntVar(root, value='Close')
varOpen = IntVar(root, value='Open')
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I am not sure how to display in the drop down menu Close and Open. Instead I got the values and the default field is empty. How can I have the Close and Open in the menu in a way that they a related to the values I receive from randint?
I want further to use the values for other operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them as a tuple:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.c = randint(1, 50)
        self.o = randint(60, 100)
        varClose[0].set(self.c)
        varOpen[0].set(self.o)
        Close = varClose[1]
        Open = varOpen[1]
        self.Mylist = ttk.Combobox(width=10)
        self.Mylist['values'] = (Close, Open)
        self.Mylist.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky=W)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('420x220')
varClose = (IntVar(root), "Close")
varOpen = (IntVar(root), "Open")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This means that `VarClose` and `VarOpen` essentially become a variable which contains two values, the first being an `IntVar()` which is set to the value of the `randint()` you run, and a string which is either `"Close"` or `"Open"`.

Doing it this way means that you have both values (String and random number) stored in the same variable, so they have an easily accessible relationship to each other.

---

For reference, you could also do this with a list:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.c = randint(1, 50)
        self.o = randint(60, 100)
        varClose[0].set(self.c)
        varOpen[0].set(self.o)
        Close = varClose[1]
        Open = varOpen[1]
        self.Mylist = ttk.Combobox(width=10)
        self.Mylist['values'] = (Close, Open)
        self.Mylist.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky=W)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('420x220')
varClose = [IntVar(root), "Close"]
varOpen = [IntVar(root), "Open"]
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One more thing. When I start the GUI default value of the field is empty although I can choose between Close and Open. How can I put the default value at the start to be Close or Open?

Comment: That's a different question, please create another question for it